# How can I configure Mutt to work properly in Cygwin?

Tags: linux, unix, cygwin, mutt

Every time I try to run Mutt in cygwin I get the following errors:

```
Error in /home/JJR/.muttrc, line 4: smtp_url: unknown variable
Error in /home/JJR/.muttrc, line 5: smtp_pass: unknown variable
Illegal instruction (core dumped)
```

And then I observe a stackdump file in my home folder. How can I get Mutt working with Cygwin successfully?

I tried visiting #mutt at irc.freenode.net which had dozens of people but no good answers, now including these two other channels which were surprisingly empty earlier: #cygwinx and #xwin

Oh, and my .muttrc was placed in /home, and not in /.mutt.
I plugged in .muttrc in /.mutt and no error, however, composing and sending messages does
not work. I modified the ~/.muttrc before evoking mutt.

Using: Windows XP SP3, Cygwin 1.7.9-1, Mutt 1.5.21

Comment: Could you edit your question to include some info about what versions of Windows, Cygwin, and Mutt you're using? There are lots of tutorials on the internet on how to set up Mutt on Windows, so more information about your setup is necessary for anyone to be able to help you.

Comment: Windose XP SP3, Cygwin 1.7.9-1, Mutt 1.5.21

Comment: @Innstanbul please [edit] your question to include that information, so that people can try to help you.

Comment: . . . . . . . . will do

Comment: Now that I gave you all the details you need, aren't you going to help?

Comment: @Innstanbul I don't know the answer to your question; I'm just trying to help you improve your question so that it's more likely to get a good answer by somebody who _does_ know how to help. You may also want to take a look at [ask] for more details about creating a good question that will attract answers.

Comment: Hmm.. how can I improve my question.

Comment: Seems like the errors listed are pretty specific - they are complaining about the smtp_url and smtp_pass variables set in the .muttrc file specifically on lines 4 and 5. You should look at the documentation for .muttrc and make sure things are legit. You should look specifically to see what you have on lines 4 and 5 and if it adheres to what Mutt expects. BTW I love Mutt, although its been years since I used it.

Comment: Will that be in the MAN pages for muttrc?

Comment: set imap_user = "YOUR.EMAIL@gmail.com" (FILLED)
set imap_pass = "PASSWORD"  (FILLED)
set smtp_url = "smtp://YOUR.EMAIL@smtp.gmail.com:587/" (FILLED)
line 4: set smtp_pass = "PASSWORD"  (Filled)
line 5: set from = "YOUR.EMAIL@gmail.com"  (filled)
set realname = "YOUR NAME" (FILLED)

Comment: I will worry about this tomorrow, goodnight.

Comment: Where did you get mutt? From Cygwin's setup.exe? It may not have been compiled with SMTP support. You can execute `mutt -v` to see the options it was compiled with.

Comment: @garyjohn: that's it (at least for me): it shows -USE_SMTP. *sigh*

Comment: The Cygwin contributor for mutt has been requested to turn SMTP support on:
https://www.cygwin.com/ml/cygwin/2014-01/msg00212.html

Answer (score 4):

I believe the Mutt with cygwin is configured and built *without* SMTP support.  If you do

```
mutt -v
```

you'll see a list of configuration options used at build time.

Here's the output from my mutt,

```
$ mutt -v
Mutt 1.5.20 (2009-12-10)
Copyright (C) 1996-2009 Michael R. Elkins and others.
Mutt comes with ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY; for details type `mutt -vv'.
Mutt is free software, and you are welcome to redistribute it
under certain conditions; type `mutt -vv' for details.

System: CYGWIN_NT-6.1-WOW64 1.7.9(0.237/5/3) (i686)
ncurses: ncurses 5.7.20091227 (compiled with 5.7)
libiconv: 1.13
hcache backend: GDBM version 1.8.3. 10/15/2002 (built Feb 26 2009 02:58:00)
Compile options:
-DOMAIN
-DEBUG
-HOMESPOOL  -USE_SETGID  -USE_DOTLOCK  -DL_STANDALONE  +USE_FCNTL  -USE_FLOCK
+USE_POP  +USE_IMAP  -USE_SMTP
+USE_SSL_OPENSSL  -USE_SSL_GNUTLS  -USE_SASL  -USE_GSS  +HAVE_GETADDRINFO
```

As you can see, it has -USE_SMTP which means there's no inbuilt SMTP support.

You should instead, install an MTA (mail transfer agent) and use mutt's inbuilt sendmail support.

I use the Cygwin `ssmtp` package.  After installing `ssmtp`, run `ssmtp-config` to configure it to talk to your ISP's mail relay and remove / comment out the `smtp_*` stuff from your `.muttrc`. You should then be good to go.